# where is the DataReader associated?How can i closed it?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

When i run my MVC(C#,use entity Framework+MySql) project, it show that:There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first. And the error code is:

```
get
  {
  return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this)
                .RelationshipManager
                .GetRelatedReference<users>("blogModel.uid", "users")
                .Value;
   }
set
 {}
```

THis code is in the model file xx.Designer.cs,I want to know how to end the GetRelateReference or close DataReader, there no DataReader in xx.Designer.cs. .

Comment: How are you handling the ObjectContext?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looping through a result-set (not necessarily this one, but sharing the same context). The simplest solution is to make sure you call `.ToList()` on any lists (from a DataContext) before you loop through them.